# Recommended Tool/Script to test Remote Desktop Performance?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

Can anyone recommend a tool to test Remote Desktop performance in Windows? Windows 7-based, both client and "server". We are making changes to network, client and server and would like to assess the effectiveness of the changes in an objective way. Currently, we just ask users *How does it feel now?*

That's fine for major changes, but it's not very objective and not always reproduceable.

Comment: +1 I agree with the need for better metrics. Users are notoriously unreliable for this sort of thing!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dated, but perhaps Microsoft's white paper could help here?

http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/d/9/4d9ae285-3431-4335-a86e-969e7a146d1b/RDP_Performance_WhitePaper.docx

Comment: Thanks for the info. I might have come across that document but did not pay much attention to it. While its content is instructive, they only mention WinBench99 as their tool. I did not spend too much time looking for it, but it wasn't readily available without giving out my email, etc. I know it's a challenge as input should travel from the client to the server while rendering can be done directly on the server (with WinBench99 for example). We'll see what comes up. I appreciate your time.